# Derivative of multi-output Gaussian Process

Tags: multiclass-classification, prediction, geospatial, gaussian-process, multi-output

I am working on a project where I estimate transition and measurements models for a kalman filter using Gaussian Processes. 
In order to linearize the models I require the Jacobian of the estimated Guassian Process.

For the single-output case this is no problem, But I am a little confused about how to do this for the multi- output case.

The posterior mean of the gaussian process would be

\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  \bar{f}_* &= \mathbf{k}(\mathbf{x}_* \, \mathbf{X}) K(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X}) ^{-1} \mathbf{y}\\
  &\stackrel{\triangle}{=} \mathbf{k}(\mathbf{x}_* \, \mathbf{X}) \mathbf{\alpha}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

And the posterior Covariance

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
C &= \begin{bmatrix}
k(X, X) & k(X, x_*) \\
k(x_*, X) & k(x_*, x_*)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  \text{covariance} &= k(\mathbf{x}_*, \mathbf{x}_*) - k(\mathbf{x}_*, \mathbf{X})k(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X})^{-1}k(\mathbf{x}_*, \mathbf{X})^T \\
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

For the single-output case this is no problem

\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  \frac{\partial\bar{f}_*}{\partial \mathbf{x}_*} &= \frac{\partial k(\mathbf{x}_* \, \mathbf{X})}{\partial \mathbf{x}_*} \mathbf{\alpha}\\
  &= \left[ \Lambda^{-1} \tilde{\mathbf{X}}^T_* (\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{x}_* \, \mathbf{X})^T \odot \mathbf{\alpha}) \right] \in \mathcal{R}_{D \times 1}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

However, my GP in this case maps $ f: R^2 \rightarrow R^2 $

e.g.

\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
        \mathbf{x}_* &= \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} \\
  P\left(\begin{bmatrix}
   y_1\\ y_2 
  \end{bmatrix} \ \vert \cdots \right)
  &= N\left( f(
   \begin{bmatrix}
   x_1\\ x_2 
  \end{bmatrix})
  \vert 
  \bar{f}_*,  \mathbf{K}
  \right)
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

But I am unsure how to formulate the Jacobian matrix of this function since I do not know the individual functions for each output dimension as I would in a deterministic case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.